# Using preg_replace to get id

Tags: php, url, get, preg-replace

how to get id url with preg_replace.

this is the link:
http://www.DDDD.com.br/photo/5b87f8eaa7c20f79c3257eb3ec0a35e0/id how do I get the id? in the case would be: 5b87f8eaa7c20f79c3257eb3ec0a35e0

Comment: did you try anything?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I recommend not to use preg_match (preg_replace would be used to *replace* something.

Simply use

```
$array = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$id = $array[1];
```

If you must use preg_match:

```
$array = array();
preg_match('#^/photo/([0-9a-f]{32})/id$#',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$array);
$id = $array[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using [`strripos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) to find the last `/` in the URL.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (($pos = strripos($url, '/')) !== false) {
    $id = substr($url, $pos + 1);
}
else {
    trigger_error('You must supply a valid photo ID');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to just extract that id string, you can use:

```
$id_url = "http://www.DDDD.com.br/photo/5b87f8eaa7c20f79c3257eb3ec0a35e0/id";
$pattern = "/photo\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/";
preg_match($pattern, $id_url, $output_array);
echo $output_array[1];
```

Or, to make the replacement:

```
$id_url = "http://www.DDDD.com.br/photo/5b87f8eaa7c20f79c3257eb3ec0a35e0/id";
$pattern = "/photo\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/";
$replacement = "your replacement";
$replaced_url = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $id_url);
echo $replaced_url;
```

[PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) - a useful tool for testing your patterns